# gstreamer python for windows

Tags: python, windows, gstreamer

I'm looking for a way to run python 3.10 project that uses Gst(gstreamer) on windows.

There are a lot of answers on Stackoverflow (from ~2014) that suggest using http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/, but this project is abandoned for now.

Is there any valid solution for recent python version to run Gst on windows?

Comment: Does this look like something that could help? https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/gst-python/1.8.0.html